# Calculating deceleration and acceleration in and out of a hard acute/obtuse change of direction

Tags: c++, algorithm, function

I have an animated athlete (football player) running at an average speed (calculated by 40 yard dash time) that is asked to change direction at ANY acute or obtuse angle.  What is the formula(s) that would calculate deceleration/acceleration in/out of the "hard" change of direction?  For example; How would I calculate the rate of deceleration into a 90 degree turn right after sprinting 15 yards (assuming 4.6 seconds in a 40 yard dahs) and acceleration afterwards back to full speed?

I guess I'm looking for some sort of algorithm or function that would help me calculate change of direction ability.  This only having 40 yard dash time, along with Height and Weight of the athlete.  I also have times related to change of direction drills, but difficult to equate simple route turns with multiple change of direction drills.

Ultimately I want to create a character that doesn't look like its running at full speed throughout the route, but must account for slow down and speed up with a change of direction. The best athletes can do this rather quickly and without much effort.

My apologies if I've tagged this incorrectly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more of a physics question than a programming one.

Comment: You have a problem with the way you've posed your question. A "hard" change in direction suggests a discontinuous velocity, meaning that acceleration is undefined at that point.